# ¿como puedo incluir materialize-css en un index.js de parcel, llamando a los archivos desde node_modules?

Tags: javascript, css3, materialize

Quisiera saber como puedo importar materialize-css utilizando Parceljs, para que incluya los css, sass y js de node_modules, en donde esta materialize inyectado con NPM.

Comment: ¿Has probado a realizar tu script tal y cómo se describe en la documentación de Parcel.js? https://parceljs.org/assets.html

Comment: si, lo he hecho asi, pero lo que no se es que si  puedo usar las rutas de node_modules o tengo que bajar materialize y copiar sus archivos en la carpeta (src). y el css es facil llamarlo en el index.js, pero el materialize.min.js no se como llamarlo, o lo inserto como script en el body como se hace comunmente?.

Comment: Debes usar las rutas de node_modules para obtener los ficheros de materialize (referenciado a través de npm). El objetivo es decirle a ParceJs qué recursos quieres importar, cuál es el destino del paquete y ParcelJs te lo empaqueta en el destino que escojas (que entiendo que será la carpeta de recursos públicos de tu sitio si estás desarrollando un sitio web).